# New colors for X

Tags: x11

In the Iron Age it was possible to edit `/etc/X11/rgb.txt` and voila, the X server knew the new names of some new color.

Parentetically, imvho this was especially useful because the `rgb.text` database had (and still has) a shortage of dark colors, and had essentially no "*numbered*" dark colors.

Unfortunately, now the X server uses a builtin version of `rgb.txt`, and doesn't care of the text file.

Is it possible to change the RGB database of the X server at runtime?

---

E.g., when I needed a few different shades of dark red for the elements of a user interface I could append to `rgb.txt` the following lines

```
      63      31      31      OxBlood1
...
...
      31       0       0      OxBlood4
```

Comment: wow! This is some retro stuff. I believe these lists are still kept around as module. Are you using some major Linux distro? Do you need the list, or what it is used for by the x server?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have the list already...  E.g., Debian has still `/etc/X11/rgb.txt` while Suse has moved the text file to `/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt`, possibly to underline the fact that the server doesn't read the color db from the filesystem., and `X` has a command line option to dump its internal color database. So no, thank you but I'm not interested in the list or the internal database, I'd like to be able to install a new color in a running X server

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe.**

The X.org [man page on Color Names](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man7/X.7.xhtml#heading11) says:

> X supports the use of abstract color names, for example, "red", "blue". A value for this abstract name is obtained by searching one or more color name databases. Xlib first searches zero or more client-side databases; the number, location, and content of these databases is implementation dependent. If the name is not found, the color is looked up in the X server’s database.

On the client side, *if the server is built with XCMS support*, [`XLookupColor`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11/-/blob/master/src/LookupCol.c#L37) reads the colorspace definitions from  [`Xcms.txt`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11/-/blob/master/src/xcms/cmsColNm.c#L57), which contains definitions that look [like this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11/-/blob/master/src/xcms/Xcms.txt):

```
XCMS_COLORDB_START 0.1
cms red         CIEXYZ:0.3811/0.2073/0.0213
cms green       CIEXYZ:0.3203/0.6805/0.1430
cms blue        CIEXYZ:0.2483/0.1122/1.2417
XCMS_COLORDB_END
```

Without XCMS (or with XCMS but no match on name), the client sends the request to the server, which initialized its color table by looping over [a static table](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/blob/master/os/oscolor.c#L847) to [pre-allocate](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/blob/master/dix/dispatch.c#L2598) the colors built from an [upstream app](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/rgb). There is no code that triggers the reallocation of colors at run-time.

It's been this way for a while: X.org [removed support](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/commit/dda10c9066a660b647384179f82e1da8e063264f) for an external `rgb.txt` file on 2007-11-05, and [documented it](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/commit/d0dd649035fc3698c5b436f9d9d248116aa106a3) on 2009-02-12.

In contemporary code, the total set of options appear to be:

1. If your build has XCMS support, then you can use a named colorspace definition to approximate the behavior of `rgb.txt`. *This is the closest fit with the prior behavior.*
2. You could poke the process memory and replace an allocated color with the desired color, but *Hic sunt dragones*.
3. You could build the server yourself, extending the table with your definition or perhaps reverting the commit that removed `rgb.txt` support.
4. You could lobby upstream to include your colors and hope they incorporate your PR.

Comment: wrt option 4, I have no more a clear recollection of the events (time flies), but I tried to lobby when it happened

Comment: wrt option 3, if memory is helping, that's exactly what K.P. told me.

Comment: wrt option 2, no, thank you

Comment: wrt option 1, `xdpyinfo` reports that I have the `XC-MISC` extension, is that covering for XCMS support?

Comment: No, [XC-MISC](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/xcmiscproto/-/blob/master/README) is protocol for [querying resource ID](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/xorgproto/-/blob/master/specs/xcmiscproto/xc-misc.xml#L43) on the X server. Xcms is a _client side_ capability, so `xdpyinfo` won't tell you about it. I'd just grep the library to see if it's referenced: `strings /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 | grep -i xcms`. You can also just look for the file and edit it: `find / -name Xcms.txt`.